# Cannot insert guest addition cd image

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

Well, I tried a lot to insert the guest additions, like type in the command line `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` or something else. But it always runs like the pictures below. My host is Mac OSX, I'm using VirtualBox.

[image]

Not look like this.

[image]

Look like this for the two command lines.

Comment: I think if I have add the guest additions successfully, there will be "Installing graphics libraries and desktop services components ... done" like the last line in the second pic which I've never got.

Comment: definitely no errors in screenshots given

Comment: Typically, it will return a failure if it didn't work, which it didn't seem to return, so it looks like all went well. Your guest additions should be installed. What's your output of `lspci | grep VGA` and `lsmod | grep -i vbox`?

Comment: I don't think so. I've tried to reinstall ubuntu several times. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you set **Auto-resize Guest Display** (HOST+G) from Virtual Box Manager View menu? If so you should be able to just drag the virtual OS window to desired size.

Comment: Please post terminal output as text, not pictures.

Answer (score 2):

The output you're receiving is perfectly normal. The Guest Additions software has been installed successfully, according to the screenshots in the answer.

You just need to reboot after the installation finishes to actually allow the kernel modules and the Guest Additions to take effect and start working.

Comment: It doesn't work, if I restart guest system, it behaves like previous. Plus, if I tried to insert guest additions again, there will be an error.

Comment: that is not an error though. sometimes right after install it takes a while for the changes to take effect after next reboot. after that it always is instant.

Comment: Oh really? Hopefully tomorrow it will be all right. Thanks a lot.

Comment: doesnt take that long usually

Comment: usually 15 seconds. has your VM gone full screen?

Comment: Not at all, still waiting, I'll update if it works well.

Comment: screen still small?

Comment: Yep, still small.

Comment: judging from screenshot it looks like you have an older version of ubuntu. what release is that?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, and that's the only version my professor allowed to grade projects

Comment: ok I thought it was older. I didnt remember that 14.04 had a launcher icon like that. 14.04 is still in support :)

Comment: So it's not the problem about the version, right?

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe update your guest additions?

Answer (score 0):

It's finally works. I just download the guest addition from the website and add it into virtual box, then run sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run in terminal. That's it.